# why do I have two tkinter windows?

Tags: python, tkinter

The following is the code.

```
from tkinter import *
def schedule_log():  
    root = Toplevel()
    root.title("My Schedule")
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=675, height=260)
    root.schedule = schedule = PhotoImage(file="my_image.gif")
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=schedule)
    canvas.pack()

schedule_log()
```

When I run it, I got two windows. One is the tkinter window with title tk, and the other one is the window with title "My Schedule". Could anyone explain to me why is this? Thank you a lot for your time and attention. 
Moreover, what is the functionality of root.schedule ? I mean, if I understand it correctly, root is an instance of the Toplevel class. So, are we trying to set an attribute to that specific instance? So, does that mean we can set up the attributes outside of the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first window is created by `Tk()` (and this is apparently done for you automatically if you forget); *additional* windows are created by `Toplevel()`.  Yes, this seems silly - I have no idea why it was done this way.  If you want to have multiple windows, all handled the same, one approach I've seen is to immediately call `.withdraw()` on the initial Tk() window to make it invisible, then forget about it completely - all of your actual windows get created by Toplevel().

Generally speaking, you're free to store arbitrary attributes in a class instance, as long as they don't collide with any of the class's actual attributes.  Also generally speaking, this is a bad idea, because you're not necessarily going to know what all of the class's actual attributes are.  However, what you see here is an idiomatic Tkinter usage, made necessary by the strange way in which garbage collection interacts with Tk images.  If you stored the image in a local variable, it would disappear almost immediately.  If you stored it in a global variable, it would stick around forever, even after the window using the image was closed.  Storing the image as an attribute of the widget or window that displays it gives it exactly the right lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

From the tKinter docs:

> A top-level window is a window that has an independent existence under the window manager.

This is a little confusing, but it seems to mean because top-level windows are extra windows, there must be a real master window. So top-level seems to create one for your automatically (I won't claim to know why or what is going on here). It is a simple fix though:

Change:

```
root = Toplevel()
```

to:

```
root = Tk()
```